# PHP display some items from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a big array which i need to display the latest 10 items in it only.
what is the best php code to do that?

thanks

Comment: define latest. as in from 0 to 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$printing = array_slice($array, -10);

print_r($printing); //or however you want to print it.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( array_slice( $array, -10 ) as $k => $v ) {
    echo $v;
}
```